# Issue with ggmaps

Tags: r, ggmap

I am running the following Code:

```
map <- get_map(location = 'India', zoom = 4)
```

But getting following error:

> Source :
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=India&zoom=4&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&key=XXXXXX
>   Error in aperm.default(map, c(2, 1, 3)) :    invalid first argument,
>   must be an array

In addition: Warning message:

> In get_googlemap(center = location, zoom = zoom, maptype = maptype,  :   HTTP 400 Bad Request

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362025/r-error-in-get-map-get-googlemap-from-ggmap

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue. I fixed it, using latitude and longitude for the location. I used 4 coordinates to locate the location. The following code shows an illustration of how you can fix this issue.

```
usa <- c(left = -125, bottom = 25.75, right = -67, top = 49)
get_map(usa, zoom = 4, maptype = "terrain") %>%
ggmap()
```

Please note: If you are trying to reproduce the above code snippet. It requires "dplyr" and "ggmap" to be installed. For a step by step tutorial on how to use ggmap. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565472/get-map-not-passing-the-api-key-http-status-was-403-forbidden?answertab=active#tab-top).