# Is there an R function to solve this ggmap error so I get my map?

Tags: r, ggmap

I want to visualize something on a map with ggmap, this is a part of my code:

```
sf <- c(lon = 5.291266, lat = 52.1326332)
register_google(key = "static-maps-backend.googleapis.com") 

map <- get_map(location = sf, zoom = 14, scale = 2, maptype = c("terrain"))
```

But I keep getting this error :

```
Error in aperm.default(map, c(2, 1, 3)) : 
  invalid first argument, must be an array
```

So I looked it up and ran the code below

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
```

After this I still got the same error as above. What can I do so this error is resolved?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Do you have a **valid** Google Key and are you running ggmap 3.0?

Comment: I have the right ggmap version. The google API I"m not sure. I can't make a billing account at the moment. Does that mean I can't get the API? @Dave2e

Comment: Yes, you'll have to set up billing account to get an api. Check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing and https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/..

Comment: There is a bug in ggmap that gives this error when the API key is not valid. https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/262

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Error in get\_map()/get\_googlemap() from ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362025/r-error-in-get-map-get-googlemap-from-ggmap)